# POD, target has frameworks with conflicting names

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

CocoaPods updated to 1.2, now I get errors.

This is my POD:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'myapp' do
pod "MTDirectionsKit", "~> 1.7.0"
pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

When I try to update POD, I receive this error:

```
-> Installing MTDirectionsKit (1.7.0)
  > Copying MTDirectionsKit from `/Users/abd/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/MTDirectionsKit/1.7.0-1e8c5` to `Pods/MTDirectionsKit`
  - Running pre install hooks
[!] The 'Pods-myapp' target has frameworks with conflicting names: googlemaps.framework.
```

Comment: Am facing the exact same issue. No update on the GitHub Issue either. (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6446). I have been using v1.1.1, it works without any problems. Let me know if you do find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue when I ran the following command `pod update PODNAME` with CocoaPods version 1.11.2.

Here's my Terminal output:

```
$ pod update Pilgrim
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
[!] The 'Pods-AppName' target has frameworks with conflicting names: pilgrim.framework.
```

## To resolve:

In Finder, navigate to the Pod folder in question. `AppName` > `Pods` > `PODNAME`. Now I saw there were two versions of the Pod (in my case the Pod is named Pilgrim).

**Delete the old version** (because we are updating the pod). In my case, I deleted the folder named `Pilgrim-2.4.2`.
[image: Screenshot of Finder which shows two conflicting versions of the same pod]
Now run the command again:

```
$ pod update Pilgrim
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 10 dependencies from the Podfile and 20 total pods installed.
```

It works!